# How to highlight nested fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nested, subquery

Although the *Lucene* logic structure, I'm trying to make my **nested fields** to be highlighted when some search result is present in their content.

Here is the explanation from *Elasticsearch documentation* (mapping [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html)`)

> Internal Implementation
>
> Internally, nested objects are indexed as additional documents, but, since they can be guaranteed to be indexed within the same "block", it allows for extremely fast joining with parent docs.
>
> Those internal nested documents are automatically masked away when doing operations against the index (like searching with a match_all query), and they bubble out when using the nested query.
>
> Because nested docs are always masked to the parent doc, the nested docs can never be accessed outside the scope of the nested query. For example stored fields can be enabled on fields inside nested objects, but there is no way of retrieving them, since stored fields are fetched outside of the nested query scope.

## 0. In my case

I have an **Elasticsearch** index containing a *mapping* like the following:

```
{
    "my_documents": {
        "dynamic_date_formats": [
            "dd.MM.yyyy",
            "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        ],
        "index_analyzer": "Analyzer2_index",
        "search_analyzer": "Analyzer2_search_decompound",
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "identifier": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "files": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_root": true,
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "include_in_root": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "and then some other": "normal string fields"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to execute a query like this:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "files",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "content": {
                                            "query": "burpcontrol",
                                            "minimum_should_match": "85%"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "burpcontrol",
                            "minimum_should_match": "85%"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "identifier": {
                            "query": "burpcontrol",
                            "minimum_should_match": "85%"
                        }
                    }
                }            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [
            "<span style=\"background-color: yellow\">"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "</span>"
        ],
        "order": "score",
        "no_match_size": 100,
        "fragment_size": 50,
        "number_of_fragments": 3,
        "require_field_match": true,
        "fields": {
            "files.content": {},
            "description": {},
            "identifier": {}
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have are:

## 1. require_field_match

If I use `"require_field_match": false` I obtain that, even if highlighting doesn't work on nested fields, the search term is highlighted anyway in *ALL* the fields.
This is the solution I'm actually using, but the performances are horrible. For 50 documents my query needs 25secs. 100 documents about 50secs. 10 documents 5secs.
**And if I remove the nested field from the highlighting everything works fast as light!**

## 2 .include_in_root

I would like to have a *flattened* version of my *nested fields* (so to store them as normal *objects*/*fields*.
To do this I should specify

> "files": { "type": "nested", "**include_in_root**": true, ...

but I don't know why, after reindexing, I cannot see any additional flattened field in the document root (while I was expecting something like `"files.content":["content1", "content2", "..."]`).

If it would work it would be instead possible to access (in the flattened field) the content of the nested field, and perform the highlighting on it.

#### Do you know if is it **possible to achieve a good (and performant) highlighting on nested fields** or, at least, suggest me **why my query is so slow?** (I already optimised the fragments)

Comment: Are you constrained to that particular mapping setup? Could you use a parent/child relationship instead of using nested objects?

Comment: Not in this case, unfortunately. I need a solution for _nested objects_. Even just solving the 2nd quesion about `include_in_root`/`include_in_parent` would be extremely useful to solve my problem.

Comment: @SloanAhrens you can write your answer regarding `parent/children` documents anyway, and I could mark it as right if it makes more sense than using _nested objects_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do here, with a parent/child relationship. I'll go over a few, and hopefully that will lead you in the right direction; it will still take lots of testing to figure out whether this solution is going to be more performant for you. Also, I left out a few of the details of your setup, for clarity. Please forgive the long post.

I set up a parent/child mapping as follows:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "parent_doc": {
         "properties": {
            "identifier": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "description": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "child_doc": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "parent_doc"
         },
         "properties": {
            "content": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added some test docs:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"parent_doc","_id":1}}
{"identifier": "first", "description":"some special text"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"child_doc","_parent":1}}
{"content":"text that is special"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"child_doc","_parent":1}}
{"content":"text that is not"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"parent_doc","_id":2}}
{"identifier": "second", "description":"some different text"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"child_doc","_parent":2}}
{"content":"different child text, but special"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"parent_doc","_id":3}}
{"identifier": "third", "description":"we don't want this parent"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"child_doc","_parent":3}}
{"content":"or this child"}
```

If I'm understanding your specs correctly, we would want a query for `"special"` to return every one of these documents except the last two (correct me if I'm wrong). We want docs that match the text, have a child that matches the text, or have a parent that matches the text.

We can get back parents that match the query like this:

```
POST /test_index/parent_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "description": "special"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "description": {},
            "identifier": {}
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.1263815,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "parent_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.1263815,
            "_source": {
               "identifier": "first",
               "description": "some special text"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "description": [
                  "some <em>special</em> text"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And we can get back children that match the query like this:

```
POST /test_index/child_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "content": "special"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "content": {}
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.92364895,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "geUFenxITZSL7epvB568uA",
            "_score": 0.92364895,
            "_source": {
               "content": "text that is special"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "text that is <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "IMHXhM3VRsCLGkshx52uAQ",
            "_score": 0.80819285,
            "_source": {
               "content": "different child text, but special"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "different child text, but <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

We can get back parents that match the text and children that match the text like this:

```
POST /test_index/parent_doc,child_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "special",
           "fields": ["description", "content"]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "description": {},
            "identifier": {},
            "content": {}
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1.1263815,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "parent_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.1263815,
            "_source": {
               "identifier": "first",
               "description": "some special text"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "description": [
                  "some <em>special</em> text"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "geUFenxITZSL7epvB568uA",
            "_score": 0.75740534,
            "_source": {
               "content": "text that is special"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "text that is <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "IMHXhM3VRsCLGkshx52uAQ",
            "_score": 0.6627297,
            "_source": {
               "content": "different child text, but special"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "different child text, but <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

However, to get back all the docs related to this query, we need to use a `bool` query:

```
POST /test_index/parent_doc,child_doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "special",
                  "fields": [
                     "description",
                     "content"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "child_doc",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "content": "special"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "has_parent": {
                  "type": "parent_doc",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "description": "special"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "description": {},
            "identifier": {},
            "content": {}
        }
    },
    "fields": ["_parent", "_source"]
}
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 0.8866254,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "parent_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.8866254,
            "_source": {
               "identifier": "first",
               "description": "some special text"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "description": [
                  "some <em>special</em> text"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "geUFenxITZSL7epvB568uA",
            "_score": 0.67829096,
            "_source": {
               "content": "text that is special"
            },
            "fields": {
               "_parent": "1"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "text that is <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "IMHXhM3VRsCLGkshx52uAQ",
            "_score": 0.18709806,
            "_source": {
               "content": "different child text, but special"
            },
            "fields": {
               "_parent": "2"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "content": [
                  "different child text, but <em>special</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "child_doc",
            "_id": "NiwsP2VEQBKjqu1M4AdjCg",
            "_score": 0.12531912,
            "_source": {
               "content": "text that is not"
            },
            "fields": {
               "_parent": "1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "parent_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.12531912,
            "_source": {
               "identifier": "second",
               "description": "some different text"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

(I included the `"_parent"` field to make it easier to see why docs were included in the results, as shown [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/getting-parent-id-in-parent-child-mapping-td4036303.html)).

Let me know if this helps.

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d69a4d6531dc063faa4b4e094cff2a472a73c5a6

Comment: Wow that was helpful :) 
I'm trying a parallel implementation using your suggestion. One thing I wonder about is if there is any way to get, as result, **just the list of the Parent documents** with relative highlighting of the found terms (either from the parent itself or from the children). Cause actually it returns a result of mixed documents (parents/children), and it needs much additional code to manage the result to show a parent-only document list.
(that's the only answer though, so probably I will finish to set it as best answer, if there are no solutions relying on _nested fields_)